# Flutter can't open file path

Tags: flutter, dart

When I want to convert my image to imagebytes, i take this error. My image type is Asset:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'content://media/external/images/media/27' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

```
_saveToDatabase() async {
if (!mounted) return;
String base64Image;
var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();
for (var i in images) {
  List<int> imageBytes = File(i.identifier).readAsBytesSync(); //this step i get error
  base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
  DateTime imageDate = DateTime.now();
  var image = ImageModel(base64Image, imageDate);
  dbHelper.saveImage(image);
  debugPrint(
      "Added: \n${imageBytes.toString()}\n${base64Image.toString()}");
  setState(() {});
 }
}


import 'dart:io';

class ImageModel{

 int id;
 String image;
 DateTime imageDate;


 ImageModel(this.image, this.imageDate,);

 ImageModel.fromMap(Map map) {
  id= map[id];
  image = map[image];
  imageDate = map[imageDate];
 }

}
```

[image: error image is here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, if you get same error you can use this solution.
Insert your project [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path), after that use it like this

```
List<int> imageBytes = File(await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(asset_image_path.identifier)).readAsBytesSync();
```

Good Luck